# How does Jack Kline's power absorption work?

Tags: supernatural

Jack Kline can suck divine energy from other beings. He steals God's power (and Amara's, since she was part of God). How does this make him stronger? Superpowers aren't physical things that you can move from one person to the next, and energy would make the same abilities stronger, it would not give new abilities.

Comment: Well, clearly one can do this in *Supernatural*. The show is *supernatural*, it does not need to obey the rules of what seems reasonable. But then, I lost interest sometime around Season  8 or 9 (5 would have been a better place to end than 15) so perhaps this contradicts some other part of the show.

Comment: Don't forget, Jack got made into some weird type of "power vacuum" by the Darkness, or whatever it was. Normal (even for Supernatural) rules no longer apply.

Comment: Although I Iove the show, the inconsistencies in the canon are frustrating. I have yelled at the writers and show runner  more than once when an episode's plot contradicted previous information - "Don't you watch your own show?" So, I simply accepted that Jack was able to suck "power" from pretty everything around him and became stronger as a result. I realized the end of the series was severely affects by the shutdowns. The last two episodes felt rushed to me.